# How to permanently enable Read Access for MongoDB Secondary Node?

Tags: mongodb

Upon trying to **connect mongodb secondary node** from application :

08:11:2018 16:01:00.552 - error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
08:11:2018 16:01:00.558 - error:  Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.  Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running?
 Error details:
 **MongoError: no valid seed servers in list**

I can access the secondary DB by manually entering the command rs.slaveOk(); , but the same wont suffice as I need the application to have dynamic read access everytime the DB is bieng queried

Comment: What is MongoDB Version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 08:11:2018 16:01:00.552 - error: A hook (orm) failed to load!
>   08:11:2018 16:01:00.558 - error: Error: Failed to connect to MongoDB.
>   Are you sure your configured Mongo instance is running? Error details:
>   MongoError: no valid seed servers in list

As per your it seems like that your mongod server has not started.

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) All read preference modes except [primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/#primary) may return stale data because [secondaries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-secondary) replicate operations from the primary with some delay. [[1]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#edge-cases-2-primaries) Ensure that your application can tolerate stale data if you choose to use a non-[primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/#primary) mode.

MongoDB [drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/drivers/) support five read preference modes.

```
Read Preference Mode    Description

primary                 Default mode. All operations read from the current replica set primary.                                                       
                        Multi-document transactions that contain read operations must use read preference primary.

                        All operations in a given transaction must route to the same member.

primaryPreferred        In most situations, operations read from the primary but if it is unavailable, operations read from secondary members.

secondary               All operations read from the secondary members of the replica set.

secondaryPreferred      In most situations, operations read from secondary members but if no secondary members are available, operations read from the primary.

nearest                Operations read from member of the replica set with the least network latency, irrespective of the member’s type.
```

As MongoDB documented [setSlaveOk()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.slaveOk/)  This allows the current connection to allow read operations to run on secondary members. See the [readPref()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.readPref/#cursor.readPref) method for more fine-grained control over [read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/) in the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell.

```
db.getMongo().setSlaveOk()
```

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-secondary/), [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-preference/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348459/errora-hook-orm-failed-to-load-when-lifting-sails-app-using-mongo-db)

Comment: I added the following in the DB accessing user home directory and seems to be working fine .  echo "rs.slaveOk()" >> ~/.mongorc.js .  My query is that  if we add the same command to a node which is primary , whether it will cause any impact on the default primary DB operation ?